# Show that $T$ is a bounded operator and $\left \| T \right \|=1$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Consider in $X=\left ( L^2\left [ 0,1 \right ],\left \| \cdot  \right \|_{2} \right )$ the operator $T:X \rightarrow X$ defined by $\left ( Tf \right )\left ( t \right )=\int_{0}^{t}f\left ( s \right )ds$, where $t \in\left [ 0,1 \right ]$. Show that $T$ is an bounded operator and $\left \| T \right \|=1$.

My attempt:

First,
$$\left \| Tf \right \|_{2}^2=\left \| \left ( Tf \right )\left ( t \right ) \right \|_{2}^2= \int_{0}^{1}\left | \int_{0}^{t} f\left ( s \right )ds\right |^2dt \leq \int_{0}^{1}\left ( \int_{0}^{t} \left | f\left ( s \right ) \right |ds\right )^2 dt \leq \int_{0}^{1}\left ( \int_{0}^{t} \left \| f \right \|_{\infty} \right )^2 dt = \int_{0}^{1} t^2 \left \| f \right \|_{\infty} ^2 dt=\frac{\left \| f \right \|_{\infty} ^2 }{3}.$$

Then,
$$\left \| f \right \|_2^2=\int_{0}^{1}\left | f\left ( s \right ) \right |^2 ds \leq \int_{0}^{1}\left ( \left \| f \right \|_{\infty} \right )^2 ds = \left \| f \right \|_{\infty} ^2.$$

Therefore
$$\frac{\left \| Tf \right \|_{2} }{\left \|f \right \|_{2} } \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} < 1,$$

and this tell us $T$ is a bounded operator.

Now I'm stuck with the another inequality. What $f$ should I set to get $\left \| T \right \|=1$? Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here you would seem to have proven that $||T|| \leq 1 / \sqrt{3}$.  It looks like one of your inequalities is wrong.  For this approach to work you'd need to get a bound on $||f||_\infty$ in terms of $||f||_2$, but I don't think that's possible.

Comment: To add to @JairTaylor comment, your mistake is that when you want to bound the fraction $||Tf||_2/||f||_2$ from above, you need to have an upper bound on the numerator , which you have, but you need *lower* bound on the denominator, when you in fact also have upper bound on it.

Comment: You don't want to work with $L^\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

We can say $\lvert \int_0^t f(s)\,ds \rvert^2\leq \|1\|_{L^2([0,t])}^2\,\|f\|_{L^2([0,t])}^2=t \|f\|_{L^2([0,t])}^2 \leq t \|f\|_{L^2([0,1])}^2$.

Hence, $\|Tf\|^2=\int_0^1 \lvert \int_0^t f(s)\,ds \rvert^2\,dt \leq \|f\|_{L^2([0,1])}^2 \int_0^1 t\,dt =\frac 12 \|f\|_{L^2([0,1])}^2$. Taking square roots shows
$$
\|Tf\|\leq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\|f|.
$$
What am I missing?

Comment: Should you prove $\int_0^t|f(s)|^2ds \leq \int_0^1|f(s)|^2ds = \|f\|_2^2$, where $t \in [0,1]$?

Comment: And set some f in order to get $\left \| T \right \|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ too, right?